# Turning off Request.Form validation on inherited button control

Tags: asp.net, html, validation

Is it possible to turn off the Request.Form validation on a per control basis? The problem is that IE 6 and IE 7 puts the content of the `<button>` tag into the `name` attribute, thus resulting in html code in the attribute which makes asp.net server shout out loud.

Notice, this only happens in IE 6 and 7 because of their erroneous interpretation of HTML 4.

Comment: Are you referring to "Event Validation"?

Comment: Yeah, it is a little unclear as to what you want to accomplish. If you simply want to disable validation when you click a button, or cause some event from the client that would normally cause validation, then you should be able to do what I refered to in my answer. If you are looking for more fine grained control, then you will need to consider using validation groups, or tapping directly into the client side validation events.

Comment: I guess were I using MVC, this might help: http://netrsc.blogspot.com/2009/04/validateinput-attribute-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

You can always set the CausesValidation property to False in your button:

```
CausesValidation="false"
```

Comment: That does not work. The problem is how IE 6/7 puts html content into attributes.

Say I do <button><b>hello</b></button>, then IE 6/7 incorrectly interprets the <button> tag and puts the content into an attribute. The form tries to send that attribute, but .Net freaks out because it seems like a script hack. http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation/

Answer (score 0):

How about you style your button with CSS instead of doing it inline with non-semantic markup? That will solve the problem and make for better separation of concerns between structure and presentation.

Comment: The whole purpose of the button element is to be able to put markup in it.

The reason why I'm doing this in the first place is to be able to very distinctly separate structure from presentation. Though, this is the web world with different browsers supporting different things, thus making me use this solution.

Comment: I'm confused--doesn't that mean that using CSS *is* what you want?

Well, anyway, you can add any attribute to an ASP.NET control and it will output it directly. So add `style="..."` to the Button's attribute/parameter list (*not* in between the opening and closing tags), and you can put CSS styles inline still.

Comment: My answer was a bit unclear. It's an advanced CSS manouevre I'm using to create what I want which needs the extra elements to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the HttpRequestValidationException thrown when form controls contain potential XSS exploits then take a look at [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039640/is-it-possible-to-remove-some-post-data-with-an-httpmodule/1147004#1147004).  I provide the code for a class module to intercept a postback before the validation event occurs and modify the form data.

I suspect however that the problem is not a bug in IE but possibly some invalid HTML or Javascript causing you trouble.