# ASP Classic Request.Form is empty after adding IIS Module

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp-classic, iis-7.5

This is driving me crazy. I have a web app that is a mixture of ASP.NET MVC 3 and Classic ASP.   The Classic ASP code is very old and doesn't really do much to prevent Cross-Site Scripting or any other vulnerability. In an effort to add a bit of security to the Classic ASP pages I created an IIS module that will intercept the HTTP request before it is processed by Classic ASP and triggers the ASP.NET validation of the request. Here it is:

```
public class RequestValidationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(context_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
    }

    void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context != null)
        {
            var request = context.Request;
            if (request != null)
            {
                string path = request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension;
                if(string.Equals(path, ".asp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    //access request collections to trigger request validation
                    var form = request.Form;
                    var qs = request.QueryString;
                    var c = request.Cookies;
                    var h = request.Headers;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This module works beautifully. However, if a valid request is sent, the object **Request.Form** in the Classic ASP code is always empty! I'm not able to get any of the values submitted in the form (or querystring). As soon as I remove the Module from the web.config the request.form is populated again.

This is an ASP.NET MVC 3 app running in IIS 7.5 integrated mode. All the asp pages are in a directory inside the MVC 3 app.

Comment: Check out the accepted answer of [Is it possible to remove some post data with an HttpModule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039640/is-it-possible-to-remove-some-post-data-with-an-httpmodule) here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MarcoMiltenburg that's not what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you need but it shows how to properly read / change the posted form data and still have it accessible for the remainder of the request.

Comment: @epignosisx Do you have answer?

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this issue too.
For Classic ASP, it should be placed in another application pool. Otherwise, Request.form does not work

Comment: Which setings should we use for application pool?